# boost creating group threads for a class function

Tags: c++

How can I use the thread group call for a class member function?

For the hole class is `mythreads.create_thread(myclass())` but for a method of my class like `get(int a,int b)` how it would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert that member function into an object that's callable with no arguments by using [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_member_pointers).

```
mythreads.create_thread( boost::bind( &YourClassName::get,
                                      your_class_instance,
                                      your_a,
                                      your_b) )
```

Comment: Thanks, and without using that bind is not possible?

Comment: Bind is one common solution. Alternatives to bind would be a new question.